# $|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be entire. Show that if
$|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$, then $f$ is constant on $\mathbb C$. How I can answer this by  considering the distance between $f(z)$ and $i$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$|\mathrm{Im}f(z)|\le |\mathrm{Re}f(z)|$ implies that $|f(z)-i|\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. It follows that $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{f(z)-i}$ is a bounded entire function, and due to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), it must be a constant.

Comment: How did |f(z)−i|≥  √  2  /2  happen?

Comment: I tried to do it but I ended with |f(z)-i|>=1.

Comment: @neno: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is the distance between $i$ and the lines $y=\pm x$, i.e. the boundary of the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|\mathrm{Im}f(z)|\le |\mathrm{Re}f(z)|\}$.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, $\textrm{Re} \, f(z)^2 = \left(\textrm{Re} \, f(z) \right)^2 - \left(\textrm{Im} \, f(z) \right)^2 \geq 0$. This implies that $f(z)^2$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

follows directly from picard's little theorem