# Proving function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ then $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228080/operatornameimfz-leq-operatornamerefz-then-f-is-constant)

$f$ is entire such that $|\mathrm{Re}f(z)|<|\mathrm{Im}\,f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. To prove $f$ is a constant function.

I know I can prove $f$ do not have essential singularity at $\infty$ for this case which will eventually lead function to be polynomial. Then I can even go further with $f(z)= \alpha z^n $ for some large $z$. Then I don't know where to go. Am I going somewhere with that or just doing something not important. Any hint much appreciated.

Comment: So it sounds like the image of $f$ would be contained a half-plane. Have you considered whether the half-plane admits a bounded holomorphic map, say, to the disc?

Comment: By Picard's theorem, an entire function that misses two values must be a constant function. Under the conditions you give for the image $f$ misses many values, so it must be a constant function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two straight $x=y$ an $x=-y$ determine 4 sets in the plan. Your function $f$ assume their values in the two sets(upper and lower strict) containing the points (0,1) and (0,-1). Now take a small ball centered in the point (-1,0) that do not intersect the straight $x=y$ and $x=-y$. How $f$ do not assume any value in this ball(say ratio $\epsilon$), we must $|f-(-1,0)|>\epsilon$. Therefore $\frac{1}{|f-(-1,0)|}<\epsilon$, $\frac{1}{f-(-1,0)}$ being holomorphic, must be constant( Liouville). And also $f$.

Another way not so elementary follow from comment above about Picard's theorem