# Proving $f$ is constant How I can answer this by considering the distance between $f(z)$ and $i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ then $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228080/operatornameimfz-leq-operatornamerefz-then-f-is-constant)

> Let $f\colon\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be entire. Show that if
>   $|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\geqslant |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$, then $f$ is constant on $\mathbb C$.

Can I answer this by  considering the distance between $f(z)$ and $i$ like in this problem [$|\operatorname{Im}f(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Re}f(z)|$ then $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228080/operatornameimfz-leq-operatornamerefz-then-f-is-constant)?

Comment: You've already found the exact duplicate.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean to switch the inequality

Comment: So multiply by $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $$f(z)-1.$$  Notice that $|f(z)-1|\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: That will do the job. Cool.

Comment: And you goota take the reciprocal and argue using Louiville theorem.

Comment: @Deepak: Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

$(2,1),(3,2)\notin f(\mathbb C)$. Also every non-constant entire function assumes each complex number with one possible exception.

Comment: Picard theorem? Any other way then that, I am not familier with that.

Comment: Eric Naslund already found it.